# VS C++ Form Process::Start

Tags: c++, windows, forms, process

Is there any way to write command line in C++ form application? There seem to be a function call in C++ that can call the CMD (`Process::Start("cmd.exe")`).

Does anybody know how to add in an argument?? So in the cmd, I want to run this command: `tesseract in_image out_text`.

Comment: The easiest way is to use the "[system()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/b4b6wz4t%28v=vs.80%29.aspx)" standard library function.

Comment: I don't get it. Do you want to start your program from cmd and evaluate the arguments or do you want to to type a command in your forms application to start a command line tool? The classical command would be exec in that case. And which API do you use?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about:
`Process::Start( "C:\\Program Files\<path>\tesseract.exe" "in_image out_text" );`
[msdn documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/h6ak8zt5%28v=vs.80%29.aspx)